# Carthage Update Not Happening

Tags: ios, swift, updates, carthage

I know it's duplicate but I have searched and tried many things but update not happening

Tried :

1. `Carthage Update`
2. `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit and carthage update --platform iOS`
3. `brew install carthage --HEAD`

> ==> Cloning https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage.git Cloning into '/Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/carthage--git'... remote:
>   Counting objects: 20918, done. remote: Compressing objects: 100%
>   (6/6), done. remote: Total 20918 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0),
>   pack-reused 20912 Receiving objects: 100% (20918/20918), 18.03 MiB |
>   815.00 KiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (13727/13727), done.
>   ==> Checking out branch master
>   ==> make prefix_install PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/carthage/HEAD-256ae62 Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully The formula
>   built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Could not symlink
>   bin/carthage Target /usr/local/bin/carthage already exists. You may
>   want to remove it:   rm '/usr/local/bin/carthage'
>
> To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:   brew link
>   --overwrite carthage
>
> To list all files that would be deleted:   brew link --overwrite
>   --dry-run carthage
>
> Possible conflicting files are: /usr/local/bin/carthage
>   ==> Caveats Bash completion has been installed to:   /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
>
> zsh completions have been installed to:
>   /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
>   ==> Summary   /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/HEAD-256ae62: 69 files, 23.9MB, built in 6 minutes 7 seconds
>
> > Please update to the latest Carthage version: 0.30.1. You currently
> >     are on 0.26.2

I could not update it.